# With Autofac, how do I enable property injection on a single mvc controller after RegisterControllers has been called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm calling Autofac.mvc.integration extension method registercontrollers in the global.asax startup

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Notice propertiesAutowired is not being applied.  I need to enable property injection on a single controller type.  How can I do that? Do I re-register the type? Unregister and reregister? I'm fearful of breaking something if I apply prop injection to all controllers at once.  Any tips, tricks, code, links, etc.. are always appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

From the Autofac wiki:
If more than one component exposes the same service, Autofac will use the last registered component as the default provider of that service.

So I think that you can feel free to re-register the controller with propertiesAutowired again to cover.

Answer (score 0):

You can register that controller manually after the auto registrations.